# React + scss styles overlapping from different files

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'm working on a project where I want to use scss with react.

**The Problem**

I'm using 3 global style files, and 1 separate scss file for each component, but they seem to apply styles that I didn't even import.

**File structure**

[image: File structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my doubt. Your Sass files are converted to CSS file and in react if you use CSS files imported as `import './somecss.css'`, your styles will leak out to other components. That's why they introduced CSS modules. If you are using CSS modules, there is a difference how you apply it. It's not like how a regular CSS class/id is applied.

> CSS Modules let you use the same CSS class name in different files
> without worrying about naming clashes.

You can get more info from [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)